# Can pgr_dijkstra use a boolean column for routing?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I want to use Dijkstra algorithm. I would like to have the algorithm find a route based on a boolean traffic column, using only roads where the boolean column value is true.

The code below does not return anything.

```
CREATE TABLE routeWithTraf AS SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.geom FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                         FROM roads WHERE traffic != false',
                67931, 5602, false, false) a LEFT JOIN roads b ON (a.id2 = b.gid);
```

Comment: Is there a feasible path from 67931 to 5602 `WHERE traffic = true`?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of a pgRouting shortest path query is an SQL statement. You can provide any query there, which returns:

- `id`
- `source::integer`
- `target::integer`
- `cost::double precision`

What does the query

```
SELECT gid AS id,
    source::integer,
    target::integer,
    length::double precision AS cost
    FROM roads WHERE traffic != false;
```

return?

If there is a result, then this result must contain also start and end ID. For routing only this selected network data will be used.

About your `WHERE traffic != false` part, why don't you write `WHERE traffic`, if you are looking for all roads, where traffic is `true`.

Comment: I want to return routing with no traffic , where traffic colums is false is return

Answer (score 0):

Is the traffic field going to be dynamically updated, or is it static ? (eg. is it to avoid congestion ?)

I have used similar properties before, but you risk that the integrity of your network graph becomes compromised, if no rout from A-B can be found. If traffic is a static field, and you are sure you have good connectivity in your graph, then it is no problem to do in the SQL.

In the setup i did, bridges with congestion became bottlenecks that the graph could not use, therefor the query returned some quite interesting suggestions...

Comment: Yes the traffic field is dynamically update